# Cell phone user and base station location dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Are there any datasets that contain cell phone users and their corresponding base stations location when phone calls were made?

It does not have to be exact location, what I am interested in is to see **a user is located under the coverage of which radio base stations**. I would prefer a large dataset (more than 1,000 base stations).

I have been trying to find said datasets and the closest one is the [Milan/Trentino dataset](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201555). However, there is no base station data so I would have to manually generate one (inc. finding base station location in these cities and manually calculating the coverage area of each base station), which is not ideal since I would prefer real-world data, it if ever exists at all.

Comment: does it have to be cell phones or could it be another technology?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe not, other technologies would be fine as long as it has the said characteristics.

Comment: Did u find any solution for it? I need the exact dataset as u want

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCellID dataset for base stations: https://www.opencellid.org/

They provide an API which is free for use by academicians and includes all nitty-gritty information about each base station in the world along with their GPS coordinates. You can then filter out for Milan/Trentino area using the coordinate box.

P.S. For a recent research that I was involved in we did use the dataset for Milan area. After filtration, the dataset has records of 900+ base stations in that area.